# Eigenvalues of matrix for linear ODE of higher order

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Say, we have the scalar ODE
$$
x^{(n)} = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} a_jx^{(j)}.
$$
We now that we can write this as a system
$$
y' = Ay
$$
where
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & \dots & 0\\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & & & 1 \\
a_1 & \dots &\dots &a_n
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
From the solution formula for the scalar ODE, we know that if $\lambda$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial od the scalar ODE (which coincides with $\pm$ the characteristic polynomial of $A$), then we have quasipolynomials $\exp(\lambda t) , \exp(\lambda t)t, \exp(\lambda t)t^2, ...$ up to the multiplicity of $\lambda$. So this means (looking at the exponential of the Jordan normal form of $A$) that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of geometric multiplicity $1$.

My question is whether there is any linear algebra (!) way to see that the eigenvalues of $A$ have geometric multiplicity $1$.

Comment: $A$ is a [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix). The question about the geometric multiplicity of eigenvalues of companion matrices has been answered e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/726317/407833)